# When is channelInactive called with keepalive on?

Tags: java, netty

I have a SimpleChannelInboundHandler which handles a few http requests:

```
CacheServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>
```

When i do not explicitly close the channel/connection and keepalive is true, will channelInactive be called every time after channelRead0 is done?

Or will channelInactive only be called once when the channel/connection is closed?

I ask this because when keepalive is true on a http connection the connection isn't closed by client and client can send multiple requests without opening/closing the connection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ChannelInactive() will only be called when the channel is closed. This is the contract.

Comment: Thanks Norman for clearing it up, the function name did make me a bit confused.

Comment: Is Channel.attr still valid in channelInactive ?

Comment: @NormanMaurer To clarify, this means that *this application* has closed *this channel*. It doesn't mean the *peer* has closed the *connection,* right?

Comment: What about `close` callback if I implement the `ChannelDuplexHandler`? When will it be called and what's the different?

Comment: close(...) will be called when "you" call Channel.close() or ChannelHandlerContext.close()

Comment: I think ChannelInactive() DOES mean the peer closed the connection, because it is triggered by inbound event [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225565/the-difference-between-channelinactive-and-close-and-disconnect-in-channelhandle]; while ctx.close()/channel.close() are outbound handlers, does not trigger ChannelInactive().

Comment: close() will ultimately also cause channelInactive(). But yes if the remote peer closes the connection you will see channelInactive().