# Why channelInactve() callback is not called after channel.close()?

Tags: java, netty

According to Norman:

[ChannelInactive() will only be called when the channel is closed. This is the contract.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20126310/4003403)

But this:

```java
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap()
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .group(new NioEventLoopGroup())
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<NioSocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(NioSocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline()
                            .addLast(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("Inactive()");
                                }
                            })
                            .addLast(new ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void close(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
                                    System.out.println("close()");
                                }
                            });
                }
            });

    b.connect("localhost", PORT).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
}
```

Outputs just: **close()**

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Let me check.

Comment: And should I create a ticket or ...

Comment: No need (you can if you want tho) I will open a PR with a fix shortly. I will let you know once done.

Comment: Thanks, Norman, that's awesome, because by now you really have to fire custom user event to inform an inbound handler about closed channel. Which is a valid W/O though.

Comment: @NormanMaurer, any progress for this question? I am also confusing with the channelInactive and close callback

Comment: This was fixed in latest netty releases.