# the difference between channelInactive and close and disconnect in channelhandler?

Tags: netty

what is the difference between channelInactive and close and disconnect event in channelhandler?

If I close the channel mannually, all three methods in channelhandler will be called?

If the channel closed by network errors, all three methods in channelhandler will be called?

I wonder if I just implment the channelInactive method, does all the close and disconnect event be covered too? I means is the channelInactive method superior than others?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that `disconnect` and `close` are outbound which is also why these are defined in `ChannelOutboundHandler` while `channelInactive` is inbound and thus is defined in `ChannelInboundHandler`.

Outbound events are events that are explicit triggered via `Channel.*`, `ChannelHandlerContext.*` methods, like for example: "I want to close the Channel". The user can then intercept these and do something, like delay closing etc.

Inbound events are triggered by the transport itself (and so the `EventLoop`) and usually tell you that something has happened (which may be because you requested it or the remote peer did so).

The difference between `disconnect` and `close` depend on the transport itself, for example when using `TCP` there is no difference while when using `UDP` there is one.

Comment: Hi Norman, if the server goes down and the channel becomes broken, how does Netty capture this and call channelInactive in the handler? Trying to find out in the code but get confused. Thanks.